# Изменить стандартную иконку drawer

Tags: flutter, dart

У виджета Drawer создается стандартная иконка в виджете AppBar, белый бургер который открывает дровер при нажатии. хочу поменять эту иконку(перекрасить и заменить), пробовал все свойства из документации, но ничего не помогло.
Может кто сталкивался и разобрался как изменить стандартную иконку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html

```
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
        tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: `Зарылся сильней в доку и нашел решение, всем спасибо, расходимся.` [Далеко зарылись, достаточно на картинку посмотреть...](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Comment: По картинке поняли как изменить этот элемент и управлять им?

Comment: По картинки я понял что это за элемент и где находиться, а чуть ниже я узнал что это просто виджет (а с виджетом можно делать что угодно).